# Identify tabs by index in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm creating tabs dynamically with names and their corresponding id's I'm getting from a web API:

```
    private fun getCategories() {
        val url = "http://192.168.1.45/companyweb/get_categories"
        val rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val jar = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,Response.Listener { response ->

            for (x in 0..response.length()-1) {
                val category = Category(response.getJSONObject(x).getString("id"), response.getJSONObject(x).getString("name"))
                categoryList.add(category)
                val newTab = navigationTabs.newTab()
                newTab.text = categoryList[x].name.toString()
                navigationTabs.addTab(newTab)
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d("HAVERI", error.toString()) })
        rq.add(jar)
    }
```

Once one of the tab is selected by the user, I would like to have a way to know to which category it corresponds. But the only thing I can get is its R.id such as:

```
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab@90eb7ca
```

I'm using the navigation tabs listener:

```
navigationTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }

    override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        Log.d("TAG", "tab selected is " + p0.toString())
    }
})
```

Is there a way to "mark" each added tab with an index, or another custom identifier, so I can recognize it later when it's selected. Using p0 in the listener isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the web id as *tag*. `TabLayout.Tab` has a function [setTag(Object)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.Tab.html#settag).

Let's assume you pass in the web id as a `String` value, then inside the functions of the `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` you can retrieve the tag by calling

```
val tag = p0.getTag() as String
```